# Wordpress keeps adding <a> tags

Tags: html, css, wordpress, autofill, atag

So while I am working with Wordpress and the OceanWp Theme (in the HTML Editor), everytime I am adding a  tag anywhere in my Code, Wordpress keeps adding  tags over and over again to my HTML Code. The problem only occurs with the  tags.

For example I have these lines of code:

```
<div class="div_wrapper">
<div class="mid_section">Test

</div>
</div>
```

Now what I want for example is a clickable  so I am adding the first  tag in:

```
<a href="http://example.com">

<div class="div_wrapper">
<div class="mid_section">Test

</div>
</div>

</a>
```

So from now on, everytime I am tapping out of the Editor, Wordpress will do this:

```
<a href="http://example.com"></a>

<a href="http://example.com">
</a>
<div class="div_wrapper"><a href="http://example.com">
<div class="mid_section">Customize your own learning plan

</div>
</a>
```

That's whats happening after 3 times tapping out:

```
<a href="http://example.com"></a>

<a href="http://example.com">
</a>
<div class="div_wrapper"><a href="http://example.com">
<div class="mid_section">Customize your own learning plan

</div>
</a><a href="http://example.com"></a><a href="http://example.com"></a>
```

I guess you can see the problem.

This keeps happening over and over again and I really don't know what I am doing wrong here.

Hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that it's not ok to put a "div" (which is a block element) inside an "a" (which is an inline element). the code should be:

```
<div class="div_wrapper">
    <div class="mid_section">
        <a href="http://example.com">
            Test
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment definitely helped me a lot. But how do I make my whole div a clickable div then ?

Comment: well, i don't have access to your entire css but most of the time styling the "a" element as a block helps. somthing like: <a href="http://example.com" style="display:block; width: 100%; height: 100%;">Test</a>

Comment: So I tried putting the <a href> tag inside a div, but for some reason wordpress tries to add several more <a href> next to each other everytime I want to add new code to it :/

Comment: Just to make sure. are you using the text editor or visual editor?